# Footnote re-starts in each page

Tags: footnotes

I am using the following shell for my PhD thesis and I have added so many packages that I am not sure which one is restarting the footnote in each page in 1. Can someone please help me? 
Thank you

```
%input macros (i.e. write your own macros file called MacroFile1.tex)
%\include{Macros/MacroFile1}
\PassOptionsToPackage{nottoc}{tocbibind}
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{CUEDthesisPSnPDF}

\ifpdf
\pdfinfo { /Title  (CUED PhD and MPhil Thesis Classes)
           /Creator (TeX)
           /Producer (pdfTeX)
           /Author (Harish Bhanderi harish.bhanderi@cantab.net)
           /CreationDate (D:20030101000000)  %format D:YYYYMMDDhhmmss
           /ModDate (D:20030815213532)
           /Subject (Writing a PhD thesis in LaTeX)
           /Keywords (PhD, Thesis)}
\pdfcatalog { /PageMode (/UseOutlines)
              /OpenAction (fitbh)  }
\fi

\title{ }

\ifpdf
\author{\href{mailto:bvgm500@york.ac.uk}{ \\  \vspace{3mm} PhD}}
\collegeordept{\href{http://www.york.ac.uk/}{University of }}
\university{\href{http://www.york.ac.uk/economics/}{Department of }}
% insert below the file name that contains the crest in-place of 'UnivShield'
\crest{\includegraphics[width=0.1mm]{UnivShield}}
\else
\author{ }
\collegeordept{ }
\university{ }
% insert below the file name that contains the crest in-place of 'UnivShield'
\crest{\includegraphics[bb = 0 0 292 336, width=30mm]{UnivShield}}
\fi
%
% insert below the file name that contains the crest in-place of 'UnivShield'
% \crest{\IncludeGraphicsW{UnivShield}{40mm}{14 14 73 81}}
%
%\renewcommand{\submittedtext}{change the default text here if needed}
\degree{}
\degreedate{ }

% turn of those nasty overfull and underfull hboxes
\hbadness=10000
\hfuzz=50pt

% Put all the style files you want in the directory StyleFiles and usepackage like this:

%\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
%\usepackage{subfigure}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
%\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage[para,online,flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{amsmath,caption, booktabs}
%\usepackage{booktabs,caption,fixltx2e}
\usepackage{watermark}
%\usepackage{draftwatermark}
%\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[L]{{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[R]{}

% Comment out the next line to get single spacing
\onehalfspacing

\hyphenation{di-fferent}
\hyphenation{subs-trate}

\begin{document}

\begin{doublespace}
\dominitoc %Per-chapter table of contents (James)
%\language{english}

% A page with the abstract on including title and author etc may be
% required to be handed in separately. If this is not so, then comment
% the below 3 lines (between '\begin{abstractseparte}' and 
% 'end{abstractseparate}'), normally like a declaration ... needs some more
% work, mind as environment abstracts creates a new page!
% \begin{abstractseparate}
%   \input{Abstract/abstract}
% \end{abstractseparate}

% Using the watermark package which is in StyleFiles/
% and to remove DRAFT COPY ONLY appearing on the top of all pages comment out below line
%\watermark{DRAFT COPY ONLY}
%\SetWatermarkLightness{0.9}
%\SetWatermarkText{\textsf{\textbf{DRAFT}}}
%\SetWatermarkScale{6.0}

%set the number of sectioning levels that get number and appear in the contents
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{minitocdepth}{4}

\maketitle 

\frontmatter % book mode only
\pagenumbering{roman}
\include{Abstract/abstract}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\include{Acknowledgement/acknowledgement}
\include{Declaration/declaration}

%\printnomenclature  %% Print the nomenclature
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Nomenclature}

\setcounter{mtc}{4} %Per-chapter table of contents (James)
\mainmatter % book mode only
\include{Introduction/introduction}
\include{Chapter1/chapter1}
\include{Chapter2/chapter2}
\include{Chapter3/chapter3}
\include{Chapter4/chapter4}
%\include{Chapter5/chapter5}
\include{Conclusions/conclusions}
%\include{Symbols/symbols}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[L]{{}}
\fancyhead[R]{}

\backmatter % book mode only
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}
\appendix
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[L]{{APPENDIX}}
\fancyhead[R]{}
%\include{Appendix1/appendix1}
\include{Appendix2/appendix2}
\include{Appendix3/appendix3}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[L]{{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[R]{}
\include{References/references}
%\printbibliography

\end{doublespace}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you really need `\usepackage{footmisc}`? Maybe it is causing the problem. This pack contains a `perpage` option.

Comment: @Sigur I load it and I have no such problems.

Comment: @Sigur But the custom class apparently has it. That's why I think "from scratch" is usually better. :P

Answer (score 4):

Your custom class is loading `\usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}` which sets the footnotes to restart, as specified, at each page.

Since you have the `.cls` file, you can open it, remove the offending line and save it.

Comment: .cls? what does that mean?

Comment: @BiancaGuizar it's the class file you downloaded :)

Answer (score 0):

You might not like my answer as it will suggest adding yet another package !
Try to use the **chngcntr** package. I know that you can use it to avoid restarting the counter at every chapter through

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}
```

This basically overrides the resetting of the counter at every chapter.

Try

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{footnote}{page}
```

Comment: nothing worked and I don't know how to start from